# Numpy: select value at a particular row for each column of a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, machine-learning

I have a 2D matrix `X = ((a11, a12, .. a1n), (a21 .. a2n) .. (am1, .. amn))` and a 1D vector `y = [y1, ..., yn]` each `yi` is between `1` and `m`. For each column `i` of `X` I want to pick out the element at row `yi`. That is, I want to pick out the vector `z = (a_(y1 1), ... a_(yn n))`.

Is there a vectorized way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
In [39]: x = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)

In [40]: y = np.array([0,3,2])

In [41]: x[y[None, :], np.arange(len(y))[None,:]][0]
Out[41]: array([ 0, 10,  8])

In [42]: x
Out[42]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

Comment: Thanks! (though it should be x.T instead of x but I got the idea)

Comment: Which can be simplified to: `x[y,[0,1,2]]`

Comment: @hpaulj, that is better.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution, `np.choose` is useful for making the selections.

```
>>> x = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
```

So `x` looks like this:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

Now the selection of the value at a particular row `y` in each column can be done like this:

```
>>> y = np.array([3, 0, 2, 1])
>>> np.choose(y, x)
array([12, 1, 10,  7])
```